# SQL Parser to identify tables used inside the SQL

Tags: sql, parsing

I am looking for a solution to identify list of tables used in a SQL query. I am able to find the table names using Unix shell scripting. but to identify which table is mandatory (**inner join tables**) & which are not (**left join tables**) - basic shell scripting is not helping much as there are too many complex SQL scenario (Nested subquery , **left join** keyword is followed by a subquery which has inner join ).

any pointers to achieve the requirement ?

Comment: When do you consider a table to be mandatory? What is the actual purpose of identifying these tables? This will quickly become very complex indeed, what if a function is used which also uses 'mandatory' (whatever that means) tables? Or a View? Or a 100 other possible options

Comment: select * from tabl1 join table2 left join table 3
on tabl1.c1=table2.c2
and tabl2.a1=table3.a100

in the above query table1 & table 2 is mandatory , table3 is not mandatory. 

Please ignore the syntactical mistake in the SQL.

Comment: sorry , replied with half details before. Added more information now.

Comment: Why is table3 is not mandatory? That query select all columns from all tables, so without it, it will return a different result. Even if no columns where selected from that table, joining it can increase the number of rows returned. So what does 'mandatory' mean, in this case?

Comment: And if we can ignore syntactical mistakes, what do you really want to parse?

Comment: if you are using MSSQL get the query plan to XML, you should be able to get what you need from there

Comment: @RegBes, apparently, it doesn't have to be syntactically correct SQL, so an execution plan may not always be available (good idea otherwise)

Comment: SELECT
    p.product_name,
    o.order_id,
    i.item_id,
    o.order_date
FROM  production.products p
 LEFT JOIN sales.order_items i
  ON i.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN sales.orders o
  ON o.order_id = i.order_id
ORDER BY
    order_id;

if the input is above query , then the output would be below. 

Mandatory : production.products 
Non-mandatory : sales.order_items  , sales.orders 

You can refer mandatory as driving table. 

I have 200 SQL queries with me which uses 15-20 tables used in each SQL. I need to identify the commonly used driving & non-driving table.

Comment: What about `SELECT P.Id, U.Item FROM PROD.Products P CROSS APPLY PROD.ItemSelector(P.Desc) U`?

Comment: Point remains, there are too many variables to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: The list of SQL which I have , mostly using keyword as "left join" , "join" , "union" , "using". I am mainly concentrating on "left join" & "join" at the moment as that is the heavily used pattern.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot)

```py
import sqlglot 
import sqlglot.expressions as exp

sqlglot.parse_one("select * from x join y").find_all(exp.Table)
```

From there, you'll get a list of all the table nodes which you can then check the parent to see if it fits your criteria.